# Loading in background

Tags: createjs, easeljs, frame-rate, preloadjs

All game assests are broken into portions according to the game Levels.
So while user play Level #1, next level is being loaded in background.

But there is a strange behaviour with the sprites when preloading is active.
Sprites are played way faster.

Here is a test case: http://cjstest.comlu.com/index.html

1. Click "Play" button. You can see a moving rect at 16 FPS speed.
2. Click "Load L2" button. You'll notice that rect has started moving faster.

Comment: You try change the createjs.Ticker.timingMode and set createjs.Ticker.framerate?

Answer (score 0):

Look this [tutorial](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Animation%20and%20Ticker/)

Use **event.delta** for the animation not depent of framerate.

```
function tick(event) {
    // move 100 pixels per second (elapsedTimeInMS / 1000msPerSecond * pixelsPerSecond):
    circle.x += event.delta/1000*100;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment! Yes, that is a possible solution. But doesn't speeding up of the sprite playback look like some bug? I expected lower FPS on background loading, but not sporadic speed ups..